# deleterow() works only for updatable resultset

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I declared my statement as `result.concur_update` ,but if I try to use `deleterow()` it is showing error that `deleterow()` works only for `resultset.concur_updatable`.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws 
 ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
{
    String driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    String user="system"; String pass="sysdb";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
    Statement st=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String query="SELECT * FROM employees";
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println("S.No\tid\tname");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.print(rs.getRow()+"\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(1)+"\t");
        System.out.println(rs.getString("emp_name"));
    }
    rs.absolute(3);

    rs.deleteRow();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the *Oracle Database JDBC Developer's Guide*, chapter *Result Set*, section [*Resultset Limitations and Downgrade Rules*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/resltset.htm#JJDBC28615):

> To produce an updatable result set:
>
> [..]
>
> - A query cannot use `SELECT *` .
>     However, there is a workaround for this.
>
> [..]
>
> As a workaround for the `SELECT *` limitation, you can use table
>   aliases, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> SELECT t.* FROM TABLE t ...
> ```

Your current query does not meet these requirements (nor those for `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`), so it is downgraded to a non-updateable, scroll insensitive result set.

In other words, you need to change your query to `SELECT e.* FROM employees e` or explicitly list the columns. I'd advise you to read the rest of that section, as it provides important information.